# DQL: groupBy suborders per webstore

Tags: php, symfony, group-by, dql

I am trying to create a query that gives me all the items sold since the last time this funcion was called upon. Those items will then be sorted per webstore and they receive an email stating what what they sold that day. I also want to give this opportunity to so called categories, which these webstores can join. a category get his own "webstore" so that in our case we can easily access order and other functions, which are similair. So that they can get an email showing items that have been sold across all webstores.

This i then want to display twig, which will then be converted to pdf and send as an attachment and emailed. This I all pretty much have working. The issue I have is making it so that I can take the items in the suborders and display them per webstore.

webstore1:
   pizza    x2
   burgers  x3

webstore2:
  cheese x2
  pizza x2

```
    public function getWebstoresBatch($latestDate)
{
    $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $webstoreRepository = $em->getRepository(BaseController::WEBSTORE_REPOSITORY);

    $q = $webstoreRepository->createQueryBuilder('w')
        ->select('w, s, o' )
        ->setParameter('latestDate', $latestDate)
        ->innerJoin('w.sales', 's')
        ->where('w.sendBatchMail = true')           
        ->andWhere("s.date >= :latestDate");

        if('w.subscription_type == 4'){ //if webstore is a category-webstore
            $q->innerJoin('s.subOrders', 'o')
            ->innerJoin('o.webstore', 'ew') 
            ->groupBy('ew.name');
        }

    $q = $q->getQuery();

    $res = $q->getResult();

    return $res;
}
```

I try to do this all with 1 query in the hope not to have to much duplicate code. But I am stuck at this stage. Whenever I try to run this I get the following error regarding the groupBy:

```
SQLSTATE[42803]: Grouping error: 7 ERROR: column "r0_.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT r0_.id AS id_0, r0_.name AS name_1, r0_.description A.
```

I do not know for certain if what I am trying is even possible this way, if I should just make it 2 functions or 2 queries I will do that.

Comment: What `if('w.subscription_type = 4')` suppose to do? It's a string, and php will always resolve it to true.

Comment: if subscription_type = 4 , basically means that the webstore is a category_webstore which means I want the orders to be groupedBy the name of the webstore the suborders belong too

Comment: You must be mixing php and sql here. Php is an imperative language, which executes instructions one by one in order they are written. SQL is declarative language, which takes a request as a whole and return data. In your particular case you build a doctrine query with php, which then translated to SQL, and executed once when you call `getResult`. The conditional php code is executed before that, and only has effect to the query builder. It is not executed at SQL level. And again, `if()` requires a boolean parameter, so php converts the string to `true`. Any non-empty string.

Comment: Okey, thank you. In that case I will just make 2 queries and resolve it that way